# draw a tree and dynamic design (schema) by CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

i have tried to draw with CSS and javascript a dynamic graph according to a data table. 
on this [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jnrjodofmzbflg/Doc1.pdf?dl=0/%22pdf%22) you will find the graph which i have to draw it using css and javascript (html).
here is an example (html and css) of what i am trying to do (but this example is not dynamic)

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">level_0</a>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#">service_0</a>
         <ul>
          <li>
           <a href="#">output_0</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#">service_1</a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">output_0</a></li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">output_1</a>
           <ul>
            <li>
             <a href="#">input_0</a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="#">input_1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
             <a href="#">input_2</a>
            </li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">output_2</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is not working??

Comment: this code is not dynamic, i couldn't make it dynamic, if you pay attention to the pdf file you will find the number of "level" is undefined and  same thing for the others "service",  "output" and "input".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for my own problem, i don't know if it's a general solution.

the code EJS

```
<div class="tree">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Niveau <%=level_selected%></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <%var type_service = null;
                                            data.forEach(function(docService) {
                                            if(docService.type_service != type_service){%>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#"><%= docService.service%></a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <% var class_output = null;
                                                data.forEach(function(docOutput) {
                                                if(docOutput.type_service == docService.type_service){
                                                    if(docOutput.class_output != class_output){%>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#"><%= docOutput.output%></a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <%
                                                        data.forEach(function(docInput) {
                                                        if(docInput.type_service == docService.type_service){
                                                        if((docInput.class_output == docOutput.class_output)&&(docInput.input != null)){ %>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#"><%=docInput.input%></a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <%}}});%>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <%}class_output=docOutput.class_output;
                                                }});%>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <% }type_service=docService.type_service;});%>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

I hope this solution be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

Your css tree looks nice so i decided to make a tree builder, but you cant create it without a defined object. Your pdf can't be rapresented without before define the number of elements and levels.

```js
$(function() {
  var tree = {
    label: "Level 0",
    child: [{
      label: "Service 0",
      child: [{
        label: "Output 0",
        child: []
      }]
    }, {
      label: "Service 1",
      child: [{
        label: "Output 0",
        child: []
      }, {
        label: "Output 1",
        child: [{
          label: "input 0",
          child: []
        }, {
          label: "Input 1",
          child: []
        }, {
          label: "Input 2",
          child: []
        }]
      }, {
        label: "Output 2",
        child: []
      }]
    }]
  }

  function buildTree(tree) {
    var html = ""
    var label = "<a href='#'>" + tree.label + "</a>"
    var child = tree.child
    html += "<li>" + label
    if (tree.child.length > 0) {
      html += "<ul>";
      $.each(tree.child, function(i, elem) {
        html += buildTree(elem);
      });
      html += "</ul>";
    } else {
      html += "</li>";
    }
    return html
  }
  $(".tree").append("<ul>"+buildTree(tree)+"</ul>")
})
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree">
</div>
```

Comment: this tree builder is very helpful, but the data is undefined so all the objects are undefined to.

Comment: you can define something to say "its undefined" inside the object and then rapresent it using some html and css....

Comment: i found a solution for my own problem, but i think it's available for a dynamic tree with an undefined length.

Comment: if you want i will post it.

Comment: post it and accept your answer if it solve your problem